# How to resolve Divi (WordPress) anchor link issue

Tags: wordpress, anchor, divi

I've setup Divi anchor links on a page but those are not working as expected. The anchor link move the page to top only, but not moving to specific section. See it yourself: http://ryanr179.sg-host.com/test/

- WordPress: v6.3
- Divi: v3.0.21

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is related to a theme update problem. You should delete this question, as it's due to a very basic issue, so not really helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by Updating the Divi to v4.22.1.

Comment: Please delete this thread…

Answer (score 0):

First check save hyperlink under setting > permalink > Save changes.
after go to Appearance > Menu and check the menus links